# Button Layout of Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to do something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
-                           |                               -
-               button1     |            button2            -
-                           |                               -
-------------------------------------------------------------
-                                                           -
-                          CONTENT                          -
-                                                           -
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

First of all, a header 50%/50% by 2 buttons and depending what I press I would like to change all the content by AJAX.

**Question 1**:
Have I the obligation to put all inside the form? No, right? Just 2 buttons:submit... (the header would be the form, or... How?)

**Question 2:**
How can I put the header 50%/50%? I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 1

No, There is no obligation to use HTML forms, in case of Ajax. You may do an Ajax request, upon clicking on an element.

Using jQuery, you may do an Ajax request typically like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://example-site.com/path',
    success: function( data ){
        $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
            $("#content").html('<div>' + value + '</div>');
        });                     
    }
});
```

---

## Question 2

You have so many options in CSS to do so.

### Option1

One may be using `inline-block`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="button">Button 1</div><div class="button">Button 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

### Option 2

another option would be to use `flexbox`:

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```